# Data for credit debt of loans for neural networks train

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

Where I can find the data for training the neural network to classify people(will or not give back the loan) for automated web services of loans and(or) banks. Where the decision to give a loan is made based on not only demographic characteristics, salary and so on common parametes...

but by  the behavior of clients on the site, as well as the substitution of information, such as the IP address or proxy server.  I.E.data for determining that the man gives false information about himself using stolrn ip, cookies, IDs and phones and so on.

Comment: Did you see this? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/10803/1511

Comment: @philshem, yes, i did, but these data without behavior of clients.(changed ip, use proxy and so on)